# Is there any way to handle multiple input xmls in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, input

Is it possible to get the below things done with XSLT? Means i will be having both source XML and MAP xml loaded into the XSLT. And in XSLT, without any hardcoding the values, i should be able to read the map xml and apply the same on the source xml.

Please do the needful.

**Source XML which has to be transformed**

```
<Book>
        <Title>C</Title>
        <Aurthor>BalaGuru samy</Aurthor>
        <Publisher>Publisher Name</Publisher>
</Book>
```

**Map XML**

```
<RootElement OrginalName="Book" ToTransform="C_BOOKS">
        <ChildElement OrginalName="Title" ToTransform="C_TITLES"/>
        <ChildElement OrginalName="Aurthor" ToTransform="C_AURTHOR"/>
        <ChildElement OrginalName="Publisher" ToTransform="C_PUBLISHER"/>
</RootElement>
```

**Output XML should be: [After Transform]**

```
<C_BOOKS>
      <C_TITLES> C </C_TITLES>
      <C_AURTHOR>Balaguru samy</C_AURTHOR>
      <C_PUBLISHER>Publisher name</C_PUBLISHER>
</C_BOOKS>
```

Thanks in Advance,
Kannan Mohan

Comment: Why are you trying to add a second level of indirection? Why not do the transform directly with XSLT and eliminate the map XML, considering this is what XSLT was designed to do? Just want to make sure you're not taking [soft coding](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Soft_Coding.aspx) too far...

Comment: It is possible, but you *will* have to either hard-code the name of (and possibly the path to) the map.xml document or pass it as a parameter to the stylesheet at runtime. Whether this is the best way to set this up is another question. It's also not clear from the example how different from each other the different maps can be.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can't hard code the values as like as in map.xml. My map xml is really big, and even source xml too. So is there any solution without hardcoding the node names?

Comment: I am afraid you are missing the point here: if you want your XSLT stylesheet to use the map.xml document, you must point to it somehow. The real question here is **why** do you want to do it this way. Your map.xml document contains (at least some of the) transformation rules. Typically, such rules belong in the XSLT stylesheet itself. Also, these rules are not written in the XSLT language and need to be "translated" by the stylesheet before they can be implemented. So what is the advantage being gained here in exchange for these complications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare your *map.xml* as an XSLT stylesheet, and use it for the transform. For example, you could write your *map.xsl* like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="Book">
        <C_BOOKS>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </C_BOOKS>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Title">
        <C_TITLES><xsl:apply-templates/></C_TITLES>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Aurthor">
        <C_AURTHOR><xsl:apply-templates/></C_AURTHOR>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Publisher">
        <C_PUBLISHER><xsl:apply-templates/></C_PUBLISHER>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And by using it you would obtain exactly the result you are expecting.

Since your question is about multiple inputs, you can handle that with the `document()` function. Using your example you could also load the `map.xml` file and create an even simpler stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:variable name="map" select="document('map.xml')"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:variable name="tag-name" select="name(.)" />
        <xsl:element name="{$map//*[@OrginalName = $tag-name]/@ToTransform}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If will load the `map.xml` file into a variable, and use that variable to search for any tag with an attribute called `OrginalName`, compare it with the current node, and replace the tag with the corresponding name in the `ToTransform` attribute. The `xsl:element` tag creates a new element with the name passed as an attribute. The `{...}` expression is an attribute value template. The expression inside it will generate a value, which is the name the element will have.

It's simple but still not very robust. Best would be to check if the tag is supported and decide what to do if an unsupported tag is found (ignore, use a default tag result). The way it is it will fail with an error if it finds a tag in the source that is not supported in the `map.xml` file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can't hard code the values as like as in map.xml. My map xml is really big, and even source xml too. So is there any solution without hardcoding the node names?

Comment: The second XSLT doesn't hardcode the names, but it requires that the mapping is perfect (there may not be errors in the map file, and all the tags that happen in the source file must be in the map file). Both stylesheets produce the same results.